# Python: Using Argument Parse to Filter in If Statement

Tags: python

New to Python here. I have a text file.

```
Name_1_Theo
Coordinate_REAL
Evergreen
Coordinate_1_728362
House
Apartment
Age_15
Name_2_Sam
Coordinate_REAL
Slyvia
Coordinate_2_839263
House
Bungalow
Age_13
```

The following is my current code:

```
import argparse


with open ('stacknamecoordinate.txt','r') as readfile:
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Filename to Script')
    parser.add_argument ('--input_category', help='Input the category')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    name = 'Name'
    house = 'House'
    real_coordinates = 'Coordinate_REAL'
    coordinate = 'Coordinate'
    age = 'Age'

    dict1={}
    maindict={}

    nextline=''

    for lines in readfile:
        if name in lines:
            dict1['Name'] = lines.strip().split('_')[-1]

        if house in lines:
            nextline = next(readfile).strip()
            dict1['House']=nextline

        if real_coordinates in lines:
            nextline = next(readfile).strip()
            dict1['RealCoordinate'] = nextline

        if coordinate in lines:
            dict1['Coordinate1'] = lines.split('_')[-1].strip()

        if age in lines:
            dict1['Age'] = lines.strip().split('_')[-1]
            maindict[dict1['Name']]=dict1
            dict1={}
```

Question:

1. May I know how to utilise the argument parse to filter the contents in the if statement of the for loop not after the whole process is done? Where when a person inputs lets say,
   **exercise.py --input_category real_coordinates**
   --input_category (variable) would come from the variables that was declared, Eg: name = 'Name'
   So the possible --input_category (variables) I could call are name, house, real_coordinates, coordinate or age

The output would be:

```
{'Sam': {'Age': '13',
         'Name': 'Sam',
         'RealCoordinate': 'Slyvia'},
 'Theo': {'Age': '15',
          'Name': 'Theo',
          'RealCoordinate': 'Evergreen'}}
```

The catch would be, the name, and age would always be there no matter which category I call. Not sure how to go about this, regex or perhaps through boolean flags?
Many thanks in advance!!

Comment: What would be an example of command used in your terminal ? What is `real_coordinates` in `python exercise.py --input_category real_coordinates` ?

Comment: @IMCoins Hi! Thanks for your reply, oh I'm using pycharm. If I were to want to filter, I would have to type exercise.py --input_category (variable) in the terminal. Typing just `exercise.py` would provide me with all the values.
Real_coordinates is from the variable I called, real_coordinates = 'Coordinate_REAL'
So the possible variables I could call, would be name, real_coordinates, age, coordinate or house.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be what you are looking for. There is one input argument for the filename and one input argument for the categories to include, this should be the exact categories in a comma delimited list.

Cli:

```
python exercise.py -f "stacknamecoordinate.txt" -c "Name,Age,House"
```

Script:

```
import re
import argparse


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script to parse a list of words')
parser.add_argument('-c', '--categories',
                    type=lambda s: re.split(',| ,', s),
                    required=True,
                    help='Comma delimited list of categories')
parser.add_argument('-f', '--file',
                    required=True,
                    help='Name of the file')
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.file, 'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()

d = {}
records = {}
for index, line in enumerate(lines):
    if 'Name' in line:
        d['Name'] = line.strip().split('_')[-1]

    if 'House' in line and 'House' in args.categories:
        d['House'] = lines[index + 1]

    if 'Coordinate_REAL' in line and 'Coordinate_REAL' in args.categories:
        d['RealCoordinate'] = lines[index + 1]

    if 'Coordinate' in line and 'Coordinate' in args.categories:
        d['Coordinate1'] = line.split('_')[-1].strip()

    if 'Age' in line:
        d['Age'] = line.strip().split('_')[-1]
        records[d['Name']] = d

print(records)
```

Comment: Thanks a ton Nebulastic!! The code works well, but is it possible to use optional arguments for categories?
If I were to input `exercise.py -f stacknamecoordinate.txt` , it would output the whole dictionary values.
And would it be possible to have 'Name' and 'Age' as always there in the output, without having to call it?
Eg: `exercise.py --categories 'House' --file stacknamecoordinate.txt` 
Output : `Key : Name , Age, House`

Comment: Yep, this is done by not checking the Age and Name in args.categories. Changed the code accordingly. Have fun!